# subclipse unaccessible repository location

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm using subclipse to manage my source versioning.
In Eclipse under SVN repository I've added some location like:
http://myServ.com/svn/Location1/
http://myServ.com/svn/Location2/
And I'm using some project checked out from these locaitons
(e.g. http://myServ.com/svn/Location1/project1/, http://myServ.com/svn/Location2/projectN/ )

My SVN server is configured to do not give access directly to:
http://myServ.com/svn/
And I've added for mistake this location to my workspace... If I Try to open me SubClipse return me an error, of unaccessible location (of course).

So If I try to remove it, subclipse/Eclipse tell me that can not be removed because is in use, and I not found a way to force this removal.

Unfortunately I can not leave it there, because when I try to tag/brench, subclipse have some problems.

I can do again my workspace, but is there any way to force the removal of this wrong location entry?

Thank you

Comment: What are the versions of Eclipse, Subclipe, Connectors of Subclipse, Subversion your are using?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your situation, but could not. I was using: Eclipse 3.7.2, SVN Team Provider Core 1.8.18, SVN Interface JavaHL 1.7.8, Subversion 1.7.8.

Comment: I'm using. 
Eclipse: Indigo 3.7.2
Subversion client adapter: 1.8.3
svn team provider core: 1.8.16
subversion Java HL: 1.7.7
I solved as described below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fastest solution: you must edit

workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core/.svnProviderState

the file is not so clear, but with a minumum effort you can understand what must be removed exactly.